# Kotlin / Android - images lose arrangement when animation starts (sometimes!)

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin, animation, imageview

I'm building my first kotlin app and I've built a simple card game. I've made some card elements to design the gamecard (like card picture, card back, card text, ...). To have it more feel like a game I made a function called "karteAnim" (card-animation) which assigns an animation to the different elements of the card. It work's fine most times. But sometimes the arrangement of the elements in the card lose their position and f.e. the images are on top of each other during the animation instead of next to each other. This happens just sometimes (like in 10% of the cases). I couldn't figure out a pattern when it happens, seems random to me.

Function which calls the animation for the different elements:

```
    fun karteAnim(tmp: Animation) {
        if (!cancel) {
            println("Start Anim")
            kartenRuecken.startAnimation(tmp)
            kartenbild.startAnimation(tmp)
            kartensnippet_bl2.startAnimation(tmp)
            kartensnippet_ur2.startAnimation(tmp)
            baumart.startAnimation(tmp)
            gesamtwert.startAnimation(tmp)
            blattart_text.startAnimation(tmp)
            kartennr.startAnimation(tmp)
            baumname_text.startAnimation(tmp)
            baumgattung_text.startAnimation(tmp)
            beschreibungView.startAnimation(tmp)
            stat1.startAnimation(tmp)
            stat2.startAnimation(tmp)
            stat3.startAnimation(tmp)
            stat4.startAnimation(tmp)
        }
    }

Example of an animation:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <set
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <translate
         android:duration="1000"
         android:fromYDelta="0"
         android:toYDelta="2000" /> </set>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrangement was lost because the dialog window was opened. A workaround with an Handler-Delay or a Toas-Message did it for me.